# Don't understand use of commas in golf ball flight equation.

Tags: notation

I found this formula that is used to represent the forces on a golf ball in the y direction while it is in flight.

$$\sum F_y = -mg-R(V_y)+F_{M,y}(\omega,V_x,V_z)$$

$R$= air resistance
$m$= mass of golf ball
$V$ = velocity
$F_{m,y}$ = Magnus Force in y direction
$\omega$ = angular velocity of golf ball

I don't understand what the commas between $(\omega,V_x,V_z)$ represent.  Does this indicate that they are being multiplied with each other?  Or, does it mean that they are parameters for the Magnus force $F_m$?

If it helps to better understand the equation, here is the formula that is used to find $F_m$:
$F_{M,y}=S(\omega_zV_x-\omega_xV_z)$
$S$= Magnus coefficient

Comment: They are three parameters of which the magnus force depends. This is the way to denote a function of several variables.

Comment: In the "helps to better understand the equation", the notation is completely incoherent with what comes before.